# How to slice a 2-dimensional np array to get successive intervals of 28 columns each?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In the first line below, I am creating a 28 x 280 two-dimensional array.

What I want to do is to create 10 arrays each with 28 successive columns.

So the first array would take all rows and go from 0....27.
The second array would take all rows and include the next 28 columns starting at 28 from the first array.
And so on.

The code below does not seem to work and I can't figure out how to get the columns offset to work correctly (increment by 28 columns for each "k") in the list comprehension.

```
test_array = np.arange(7840).reshape(28, 280)
image_parts_1 = [test_array[:, k:k+28] for k in range(10)]  # does not seem to be correct.
```

Tried various combinations but none thus far have worked.

Appreciate in advance any suggestions or help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is the answer that you are looking for:
`image_parts_1 = [test_array[:, k:k+28] for k in range(0,280,28)]`

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!! I did not know about the options for range. Really appreciate your help.